# Camera app working fine in Marshmallow API 23, but while taking camera in API grater than 23 is crashing

Tags: javascript, android

I created a simple app to taking photos that will store in the `SURVEYASSIST` folder in the SD card. It is working fine in my mobile Redmi 3s prime (Android version Marshmallow 6.0.1), but when I open the app in Redmi Note 5 pro (Oreo 8.1.0) and click on the camera button, the app is crashing. And error code is attaching as seen in the image.

[image: screenshot of error code]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1777;
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    public static final String Demo_ImagePath ="/storage/emulated/0/SURVEYASSIST/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                String imgcurTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                String _path = Demo_ImagePath + File.separator + imgcurTime + ".jpg";
                File file = new File(_path);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any problem in "intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));" ?

Comment: Where is the crash? What does logcat say?

Comment: pls open this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZCjH.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The `FileUriExposedException` is what is being thrown. From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException):

> The exception that is thrown when an application exposes a file:// Uri to another app.

There's a good article on how to fix this [here](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0) but I will summarize in case the link goes dead at some point:

1. Add this to your manifest:

   ```
   <manifest ...>
     <application ...>
         <provider
             android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
             android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
             android:exported="false"
             android:grantUriPermissions="true">
             <meta-data
                 android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                 android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
         </provider>
     </application>
   ```
2. Create XML file res/xml/provider_paths.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
   </paths>
   ```
3. Change your code:
   From:

   ```
   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
   ```

   To:

   ```
   Uri apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this, 
                        this.getApplicationContext()
                        .getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
   intent.setDataAndType(apkURI, "image/*");
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   ```

Comment: sir, by using this, can i get the photos in SURVEYASSIST folder in sd card?  actually it is working fine in my Redmi 3s prime Marshmallow

Comment: what i have to replace at the position of context?

Comment: I updated the code. Use `this` and `this.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: C:\Users\MELVIN\AndroidStudioProjects\testcamera\app\src\main\java\com\example\testcamera\MainActivity.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
                        this.getApplicationContext()
                            ^